# Python csv : writing to a different directory

Tags: python, csv

I'm downloading files from a site and I need to save the original file, then open it and then add the url that the file was downloaded from and the date of the download to the file before saving the file to a different directory.

I've used this answer to amend the csv: [how to Add New column in beginning of CSV file by Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872077/how-to-add-new-column-in-beginning-of-csv-file-by-python)

but I'm struggling to redirect the file to a different directory before the write() function is called.

Is the best answer to write the file and then move it, or is there a way to write the file to a different directory within the open() function?

```
if fileName in fileList:
    print "already got file "+ fileName
else:
    # download the file
    urllib.urlretrieve(csvUrl, os.path.basename(fileName))
    #print "Saving to 1_Downloaded "+ fileName

    # open the file and then add the extra columns
    with open(fileName, 'rb') as inf, open("out_"+fileName, 'wb') as outf:
        csvreader = csv.DictReader(inf)

        # add column names to beginning
        fieldnames = ['url_source','downloaded_at'] + csvreader.fieldnames  
        csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(outf, fieldnames)
        csvwriter.writeheader()
        for node, row in enumerate(csvreader, 1):
            csvwriter.writerow(dict(row, url_source=csvUrl, downloaded_at=today))
```

Comment: are you creating a new out file?

Comment: Yes, I need to create a new outfile.

Comment: why not just create the file in the directory that you want to save it to when opening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe both would work.
To me it seems the neatest way to do it would be to append to the file and relocate it afterwards.

Have a look at:
[shutil.move](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.move)

I belive rewriting the entire file would be less efficient.

Comment: have you timed the code to see which is more efficient?

Comment: The code runs once a week, so speed isn't the most important element, I just want to write fewer lines if possible (less to go wrong later).

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to rebuild the file, try using the time module to create a time stamp string for your file name, and using os.rename to move your file.

Example - this just moves the file to your specified location:

os.rename('filename.csv','NEW_dir/filename.csv')

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have to save a copy of the file in its raw 'untouched' state (inc filename) to provide an accurate archive of the source data, then all amendments are saved to a diff directory. Appreciate the advice re. os.rename... that will work nicely thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Went with an additional routine using shutil in the end:

```
# move and rename the 'out_' files to the right dir
source = os.listdir(downloaded)

for files in source:
    if files.startswith('out_'):
        newName = files.replace('out_','')
        newPath = renamed+'/'+newName
        shutil.move(files,newPath)
```